# Select Dropdown to update Data table in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, drop-down-menu, datatable, flutter-test

i am stuck trying to update a Data table based on a dropdown.
I have a data table which is as a result of post API which is working fine I get my data table correctly. The same I need to update based on the items in dropdown as in on selecting the first item its should give the equivalent result in Data table and on selecting second one it should give the equivalent result for second item and so on... Is there any way i could do so?
Thanks in advance.

Post API request.

```js
  Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
        var url = 'ApiUrl';
        var response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        });
        var abc = List<Data>();
        // print(response.body);
        // print(response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var body = json.decode(response.body);
          for (var noteJson in body) {
            abc.add(Data.fromJson(noteJson));
          }
        }
        return abc;
      }
    
    This is how I created a dropdown.
    DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: dropdownValue,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                            iconSize: 24,
                            elevation: 8,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            hint: (Text(
                              'Select Type',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                            )),
                            underline: Container(
                              height: 2,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                dropdownValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                            items: <String>[
                              'item1',
                              'item2',
                              'item3'
                            ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(
                                  value,
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
```